# Import inside python package

Tags: python, import, package, init

I have a package with the following structure:

```
rank
    RankingClasses
        __init__.py
        ranking.py
        bordaranking.py
        condorcetranking.py
    __init__.py
main.py
```

`RankingClassses/`**`init`**`.py` :

```
from . import ranking
from . import bordaranking
from . import condorcetranking
```

`rank/init.py` :

```
from . import RankingClasses
```

I got import of ranking inside other class files:

```
from ranking import Ranking
```

And in main i would like to import my package.

`main.py` :

```
import rank

print(rank)
```

I got an exception:

```
    from ranking import Ranking
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ranking'
```

Before I created the package, I only had the `RankingClasses` folder and two `__init__.py` with the current contents. And everything worked..

How do I properly do file imports within a package, so that I can only `import rank` and create class objects from this package?

I've been looking at guides on creating packages in python. And now I'm trying to create my own by packing classes into it. How do I set up imports inside the package so that the user can only enter `import rank` and create objects?